# Insert aggregates into array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get an array of the aggregates in the following query (which does not work)

```
select
    c.app_id,
    90 as interval,
    'day_of_week' as group,
    array_agg(
        count(extract(dow from c.inserted_at) = 0 or null),
        count(extract(dow from c.inserted_at) = 1 or null),
        count(extract(dow from c.inserted_at) = 2 or null),
        count(extract(dow from c.inserted_at) = 3 or null),
        count(extract(dow from c.inserted_at) = 4 or null),
        count(extract(dow from c.inserted_at) = 5 or null),
        count(extract(dow from c.inserted_at) = 6 or null)
    ) as series
from conversations c
left join apps a on c.app_id = a.id
where c.inserted_at::date > (current_date - (90  || ' days')::interval)::date
group by app_id
```

It throws a syntax error

Comment: `ARRAY[count(...), ...] as series`?

Answer (score 1):

Ryan is right, what you're doing is one aggregate (`array_agg`) consuming another  (`count`). That's not correct.

Try `ARRAY[..]` as suggested.